# how to get values from mongodb document Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using java and mongoDB. I have the following json,

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "524a27a318c533dc95edafe1"} , "RoomNumber" : 516 , "RoomType" : "presidential" , "Reserved" : true , "RegularRate" : 400.0 , "Discount" : [ 0.85 , 0.75 , 1.0 , 1.0] , "DiscountedRate" : 0}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "524a27a318c533dc95edafe2"} , "RoomNumber" : 602 , "RoomType" : "presidential" , "Reserved" : false , "RegularRate" : 500.0 , "Discount" : [ 1 , 0.75 , 1.0 , 1.0] , "DiscountedRate" : 0}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "524a27a318c533dc95edafe3"} , "RoomNumber" : 1315 , "RoomType" : "Single" , "Reserved" : true , "RegularRate" : 100.0 , "Discount" : [ 1 , 1 , 1.0 , 1.0] , "DiscountedRate" : 0}

In the collection the documents have different room numbers. If I know a room number how would i get a document with that room number and then get all ther other values in that document.

for exmaple if I have 602, i want to be able to get roomtype: presidential, reserved: false, Regular rate: 500

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell query for that would be:

```
db.rooms.findOne({RoomNumber: 602}, {RoomType: 1, Reserved: 1, RegularRate:1, _id: 0});
```

And using the native mongo driver:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("RoomNumber", 602);
BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject("RoomType", 1);
projection
.append("Reserved", 1)
.append("RegularRate", 1)
.append("_id", 0);
DBObject result = collection.findOne(query, projection);
```

Comment: oh thanks that's helpful, but what if I had variables in my java code like String roomType, boolean reserved, and double regular and want to set these values to what I get from the query so I can use then later in my code, how would i do that?

Comment: Use the `result` object for that. Each key-value pair will be contained within `result`. To assign `reserved`, for e.g., use: `boolean reserved = (boolean) result.get("Reserved");`